# label value set in javascript not showing server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am setting value of `asp:label` in JavaScript but it is blank on server side on button click.

what can be the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Text property of asp:label in Javascript PROPER way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128530/set-text-property-of-asplabel-in-javascript-proper-way)

Comment: The issue could be in your code.. Could you share the relevant part of it?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#<%= label1.ClientID%>").text("SetYourTextHere");
```

Using javascript:

```
document.getElementById("<%= label1.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "SetYourTextHere";
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume ( you should show what you've tried ) that you've used the `value` attribute.

Use `innerHTML` instead. A [`SPAN`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) does not have a `value` attribute.

```
var lbl = document.getElementById("Label1");
lbl.innerHTML = "Hello World";
```