# label text set in javascript not showing label text on server side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I know my question is duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819949/label-value-set-in-javascript-not-showing-server-side) but still facing problem

In my **javascript code** I have tried different way of assigning text to label are

```
 function fileuploadvalidation() {
document.getElementById("<%=lableid.ClientID%>").Text = "hello"; 
document.getElementById("<%=lableid.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "hi";
}
```

and its use to be seen text on my .aspx page also but when I used to fetch that text on my server side it is coming blank.

**.html page code**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel16" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btn_browse" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btn_browse_Click" OnClientClick="return fileuploadvalidation();" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Label ID="lableid" runat="server" Text="" Style="font-size: small; font-weight: 400;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></asp:Label> 
</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**.cs code**

```
protected void btn_browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string abc = lableid.Text;// This is coming null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `hidden-field` to store the value that you set,then access it in code behind

add a hidden field

```
 <input type="hidden" id ="hiddenfieldid" runat="server" />
```

.

```
function fileuploadvalidation() {
    document.getElementById("lableid").value = "hello"; 
    document.getElementById('hiddenfieldid').value= "hello"; 
}
```

then retrieve it in `code behind`.

```
string abc = hiddenfieldid.value;
```

Comment: not working,i have tried and even label is also not showing on .aspx

Comment: hey its working, can you make me 1 more favour?? The text showing on .aspx page gets blank as i used to click the button, what should i do for not to make that label text blank

Comment: @MiteshJain just set the value of the hidden field back to the label in code behind,or you may use jquery to set the value using the val function

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add set the value property of the label

```
 var lbl = document.getElementById("<%=lableid.ClientID%>")
 lbl.value = "hello";
```

Comment: try removing the clientClick to see if your postback is okay and has the value

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
 $('#lableid').val($('#lableid').val().replace($('#lableid').val(), "hello"));
```

Comment: you should probably let the asker know that they need to use JQuery for this solution

Comment: Yes Mitesh Jainyou you really need http://jquery.com/  or  Use hidden-field like Sajad Lfc  say

Comment: firstly is the "Hello" text set to the label ?