# How to refer to a TextBox in JavaScript inside an ASP.NET control?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET control with some text fields and a checkbox. I would like to modify the checkbox state using JavaScript based on the values present in the text fields after page load.

How can I reliably read the text field values in JavaScript? I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/641316/33080) but it didn't help:

```
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("something") %>' ID="txtSomething" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($('#<%= txtSomething.ClientID %>').val());
</script>
```

This doesn't work; VS tells me that "`txtSomething` is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

How else can I refer to that text box in JavaScript?

Comment: Where is this `txtSomething` located? For example, inside GridView, Panel. Please post its parent control codes.

Comment: @Win It was inside an `<asp:FormView>`. I've got this working now, using `frm.FindControl("txtSomething").ClientID`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to get client ID of control which contains your text box and after search in his children input which ID contains your text box server ID

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($('#<%= parentControl.ClientID %>').find("input[id$='txtSomething']").val());
</script>
```

As another option you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($('#<%= (parentControl.FindControl("txtSomething")).ClientID %>').val());
</script>
```

Comment: If you meant `Parent`, I just tried that; unfortunately `Parent.FindControl("txtSomething")` is null.

Comment: Not Parent but ID of control where your txtSomething placed

Comment: It will be nice if you provide code with this textbox parent control, because second approach will not work with GridView and etc.

Comment: This put me on the right track, thanks. It was inside an `<asp:FormView>` which had an ID of `frm`. Using `frm.FindControl("txtSomething")` worked perfectly.